# 3rd party Wix libraries

Tags: deployment, installation, wix, wix3

I am just getting started with Wix.  I see there there a several libraries included with the default Wix install.  I also see that users can create their own libraries(wixlibs).  Are there any 3rd party Wix libraries out there that add additional functionality to Wix that may not come packaged with the default install?

Answer (score 3):

check out [AppSecInc](http://msiext.codeplex.com/) I've used their wix libraries and ui dialogs and they are pretty awesome

Answer (score 0):

a quick Google search doesn't really return a lot of good results, so I'm guessing there aren't a lot out there right now. Anytime we want to do something special at our company, we use Custom Action dlls (which can be made in .NET code).